# div width not taking up all the space available in angular with multiple components

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, tailwind-css

This project is done with Angular and Tailwind CSS.

Issue:
My divs do not take up all the space available. Each 'a' is a div with a blue background color. The whitespace is the empty space I would like to get rid of
[image: image of output]

My code:
Here are the simplified contents of my main html file

```
      <div class="container !mx-0 flex flex-row justify-between">
        <app-photo-card
          *ngFor="let photo_card of photo_cards"
          [photo_card]="photo_card"
          [class]="'w-full'"
        ></app-photo-card>
      </div>
```

simplified contents of main ts file

```
  photo_cards = [
    {
      title: 'a',
      content: "",
      img_src: '',
    },
  ];
```

and here are the contents of my photo card component html file

```
<div class="w-full">
  <div class="w-full bg-blue-500">a</div>
</div>
```

Tried a similar version of this code with vanilla html and css and it seemed to work as expected. Really unsure on what I'm doing wrong here.

Expected output would be the 4 'a' divs with the blue background spanning across the screen which would result in no whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my issue was that the tailwind css `container` class has a `max-width` property setting.

```
class       breakpoint    properties

container   None          width: 100%;
            sm (640px)    max-width: 640px;
            md (768px)    max-width: 768px;
            lg (1024px)   max-width: 1024px;
            xl (1280px)   max-width: 1280px;
            2xl (1536px)  max-width: 1536px;
```

Removing the `container` class worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flexbox, use class `flex-grow` instead of `w-full`.
here is an example [check here](https://Here%20is%20a%20much%20simpler%20solution%20in%20my%20opinion,%20while%20still%20using%20flexbox.%20I%20achieve%20that%20by%20adding%20flex-grow%20class%20to%20the%20component%20instead%20of%20w-full.)

```
<div class="container flex flex-row justify-around">
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="w-full bg-red-500 text-center">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="w-full bg-red-400 text-center">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="w-full bg-red-300 text-center">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="w-full bg-red-200 text-center">a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular's component have implicitely set `display: inline` to it, which means that the component will take as much space as it's content. That's the reason setting a width to it, does not have any effect. Try setting `display: inline-block` to your `app-photo-card` component (either from the parent or from the component itself using the `host` selector.

Comment: Thanks for your input but that didn't seem to be my issue. I tried adding inline-block and block classes to the component selector using [class] but there were no changes.

class w-full definitely has an effect as the blue background would only apply to the width of the div content ('a') without the class included.

Comment: @jspoh that's indeed the solution, the issue is that you probably did not apply this solution to all parent elements. You have to go back up until the `body` tag and display everything as block (when needed), and give them the according height (usually `100%` so that it fills the parent)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler solution in my opinion, while still using flexbox. I achieve that by adding `flex-grow` class to the component instead of `w-full`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container flex flex-row justify-around bg-gray-300">
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="w-full bg-blue-500 text-center">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="w-full bg-blue-400 text-center">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="w-full bg-blue-300 text-center">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <div class="w-full bg-blue-200 text-center">a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```